# inferred iPhone size not adequate

Tags: iphone, xcode, size

I am trying to develop for the iPhone 6 and I have an issue here that has been discussed on S.O. before, but the solution that developers have offered is not working for me.

I have taken a few pictures to try to show better what is happening.

This first screenshot is just to show that I have my Launch Images loaded:

[image]

The next picture:

[image]

Shows at the left the storyboard. As you can see the image fits the screen. The size on the inspector is "inferred" and the dimensions of it I can check by looking the size inspector:

They are 320 by 564 which corresponds to the iPhone 5s.

On the simulator as you can see there is a white gap around. and the picture at the right is a screenshot from the device running the same thing.

So to recap, i want to make an app for the iPhone 6 but on the storyboard the "inferred" dimensions are those of the iPhone 5. The simulator displays an iPhone 6 but with an image that doesn't fit and the device -weirdly- displays the image correctly.

On the next picture I have changed "Inferred" to iPhone 4.7-inch:

[image]

And I have also resized the image to fit the bigger scene on the storyboard, its now 375 by 667:

[image]

So, the normal size for an iPhone 6.

As you can see, the simulator now shows the display correctly but the device (screenshot on the right) is not correct as the image is now too big for the screen (there is no white space around the "E").

I have researched this and everyone seems to say that loading the launch images makes xCode display correctly for the iPhone 6, but that's not happening here. So what else am I missing? Thanks.